# Mostrar excel con Angular 8

Tags: angular

Necesito mostrar, en una página construida con Angular 8, un archivo de excel que obtengo de un servicio. He buscado algunas opciones pero algunas ya no tienen soporte o son para comprar.

Comment: Gracias por la información.

Comment: Estas buscando mostrarlo o descargarlo?

Comment: mostrarlo, ya lo puedo descargar

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debe hacer es obtener el archivo excel y convertirlo en json,luego con el json ya puede pintar alguna tabla en el html de angular,yo hice este metodo que me permitio convertir un excel a json

```
public excelToJson(file: File){
         this.flag = false;
         let fileReader = new FileReader();
         fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
         fileReader.onload = (e) => {
             this.arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
             var data = new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer);
             var arr = new Array();
             for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
             var bstr = arr.join("");
             var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});
             var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
             var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
             this.jsontext = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json<string>(worksheet,{raw:true});
         }

         fileReader.onloadend = (e) =>{
             this.flag = true;
         }
  }
```

Lo unico que debes es pasarle el excel dentro de una variable de tipo File,ahora necesita de un metodo que lea ese json y lo convierta en objeto que tenga el tipo de cada fila del json:

```
this.jsonTmp = this.excelService.getJsonText();

    this.jsonTmp.forEach(json => {

      count++;
      if (count > 8) {
        if (count % 2 != 0) {
          var obj = JSON.stringify(json);
          var result = JSON.parse(obj);

          let ObjetoPropio: objetoPropio = new ObjetoPropio();

          objetoPropio.dato1 = (result['__EMPTY_6']);
          objetoPropio.dato2 = (result['__EMPTY_9']);
          objetoPropio.dato3 = (result['__EMPTY_7']);

          let dato4 = result['__EMPTY_8'];
          let dato5 = "SINRESULTADO";
          if(dato1 != undefined){
            if(labo.trim() != ""){
              dato1 = "Sin dato";
            }
          }
        }
    })
     console.log(strike)
    if (strike <= 4) {
      this.cargarTabla();
    } else {
      this.objetoPropio = new Array<ObjetoPropio>();
      this.blocked = false;
      this.addSingle("El archivo cargado no es el correcto para este modulo", "warn");
    }
    this.blocked = false;
  }
```

De esta forma pasa el excel a json y el json lo castea al tipo de objeto que usted cree para mostrarlo en la tabla que vaya a utilizar, de esta forma puede mostrar los datos del excel en angular